# How to prove Law of excluded middle using 10 axioms of Intuitionistic logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

> How to prove Law of excluded middle using 10 axioms of Intuitionistic logic?

Comment: Can you elaborate more and explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: IGOR$\times 2$: please respect the people at this site, and site guidelines, if you continue to post here!  "What?" - I'll let you know that referring to a specific law, as in this case, requires that  you express the law/theorem, as you know it, within your post.  Also, there are many more intuitionistic logics than you seem to acknowledge: each varying in the allowable axioms and/olr rules of inference.  So please identify the axioms you have at your disposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Law of the Excluded Middle cannot be proved within intuitionistic propositional logic: $p\lor \lnot p$,

just as double-negation elimination cannot be proved in the said system. I.e. Intuitionistic logic does not recognize that $\lnot \lnot p \equiv p.$

See [Intuitionistic Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic).

Comment: But then how to prove that there exist two irrational numbers a and b such that a^b is rational or smth like this within Intuitionistic logic?

Comment: That isn't what you even asked in the first place. Please inform your understanding of intuitionistic logics by reading the entry I linked to, to see what tools you *do* have to work with.  Also note that proving the existence of x, y....... such that .....P(x, y) holds, can be proven if you can provide, in your case, a specific pair, a, b, for which your proposition holds.  To disprove, your task would be to prove the non-existence of any such x,y,$